# Infinite loop and I don't know why

Tags: c

I want to use the comparison of two strings as a condition of a cycle,
but the cycle goes into infinite loop and I do not know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(int a[], char *comando, char *aux) {
    fgets(aux, 35, stdin);
    sscanf(aux, "%s %d  %d", comando, &a[0], &a[1]);
}

int table_size=10;
int ar_temp[2];
char comando[2];
char aux[35];

int main() {

    while((strcmp (comando, "X"))!=0 || (strcmp (comando, "x")!=0)) {
        input(ar_temp, comando, aux);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Help me please

Comment: Be careful -- if your declarations were not *global*, you would invoke *Undefined Behavior* on your first call to `strcmp (comando, "X")` by attempting to read from an uninitialized valued (either by luck, happy accident, or clear understanding that is avoided above...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is wrong, the while statement always evaluated to true.

```
while((strcmp (comando, "X"))!=0 || (strcmp (comando, "x")!=0))
```

It should be:

```
while((strcmp (comando, "X"))!=0 && (strcmp (comando, "x")!=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

> While (I am not a llama) or (I am not a dog) ...

Even llamas and dogs will have a true result for *one* of those sub-clauses so, since true or anything is true, the statement will always result in true.

What you need instead is (reverting back to your *actual* code rather than my slightly ridiculous example):

```
while ((strcmp (comando, "X") != 0) && (strcmp (comando, "x") != 0)) {
//                                  ^^
//                          and rather than or
```

You'll notice I've also "fixed" your first clause so that the use of parentheses is consistent, moving the `)` to *after* the `0`.

Of course, if you have any other places where you check `comando`, it may be worth just making it single case up front, then you only ever need to check the lower case variant.